# XAMPP Apache Server issuing undesired 301 redirect for REST API

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

GET and POST requests such 'http://localhost/api/inquiry' are being 301 redirected to 'http://localhost/api/inquiry/' (note addition of trailing slash)

I don't know why but would very much like to make it STOP!

GET 'http://localhost/api/inquiry/7' performs as expected (NO 301 redirect

XAMPP
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1f PHP/7.4.4

### .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule api/inquiry/(\d+)$ api/inquiryController.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule api/inquiry$ api/inquiryController.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

### ERRORLOG

```
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:16.707754 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18500:tid 728] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.684722 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/api/inquiry -> api/inquiry
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.684722 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern 'api/inquiry/(\\d+)$' to uri 'api/inquiry'
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.684722 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/api/inquiry -> api/inquiry
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.684722 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern 'api/inquiry$' to uri 'api/inquiry'
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.684722 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] rewrite 'api/inquiry' -> 'api/inquiryController.php'
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.685722 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] add per-dir prefix: api/inquiryController.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/api/inquiryController.php
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.685722 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/api/inquiryController.php -> /api/inquiryController.php
[Thu Apr 30 09:17:23.685722 2020] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 18500:tid 1892] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:62841] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#25a54c39968][rid#25a57648a60/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] internal redirect with /api/inquiryController.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

### ACCCESS LOG

```
::1 - - [30/Apr/2020:09:17:23 -0400] "GET /api/inquiry HTTP/1.1" 301 336 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be solved by adding the following to .htaccess; Will continue testing and report any side effects.

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>

DirectorySlash Off

</IfModule>
```